# Why is dispatchEvent taking so long to execute and how can I improve the performance?

Tags: event-observer, ee-1.14, mongo

my company is experimenting with using mongoDB to store our categories and products. We've gotten the mongogento extension set up and working, but we noticed that performance is extremely poor when saving categories. I traced the issue to the following line in `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` which is taking more than a minute to execute:

> Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_commit_after',
>   $this->_getEventData());

In our case the line is the dispatching the `catalog_category_save_commit_after` event. I performed a grep on the whole code base and found only two methods that are triggered by this event: `saveCategoryCustomRedirect` and `processCategorySaveEvent`, neither of which take a significant amount of time.

I was wondering if anyone has had similar issues when moving to mongogento or can enlighten me to why the dispatchEvent is taking so long.